# Phases and order in condensed matter beyond Landau

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-phase

All materials in our world consist from electrons and nucleus. They non-trivially interact and can create different states of matter with very different properties. Some states of matter (or phases) are well-known: liquid, solid state, gas, plasma, ferromagnetic, antiferromagnetic, etc. All this phases are naturally understand in Landau-Ginsburg approach. Every state is determined by dimension of space and symmetry properties.

Now, I often face with different discussions of phase of matter **beyond Landau-Ginsburg** approach. And as I understand, exist many? new phases:

1) topological phases

2) symmetry protected topological phases (SPT)

3) quantum phases

4) invertible topological phases

5) ...

I wanna to clarify **differences** between this phases. Also very useful to have **simplest examples** for each of this phases.

Each of phases based in some new (for me in this area) mathematical framework. For example, LG theory based on group theory. What kind of mathematics relevant for this phases?

I will be appreciated for all answers!

Comment: There is a good review there https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.03911.pdf

Comment: Thank you! It is really good. But if it is possible, please describe differences here.

Comment: I think it is important to separate the *phases*, which are the physical reality, and the mathematical approaches used to describe them. While there are certainly approaches used more for one type of problem than for others, the same phase can be described differently and its properties (and how it differs from other phases) ultimately do not depend on the math that we use.

Comment: @Nikita See simple explanation here https://physics.aps.org/topological-phases